# What is wrong with my cython implementation of erosion operation of mathematical morphology

Tags: numpy, image-processing, cython, mathematical-morphology

I have produced a naive implementation of "erosion". The performance is not relevant since I just trying to understand the algorithm. However, the output of my implementation does not match the one I get from `scipy.ndimage`. What is wrong with my implementation ?

Here is my implementation with a small test case:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# a small image to play with a cross structuring element
imgmat = np.array([
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
])
imgmat2 = np.where(imgmat == 0, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
imarr = Image.fromarray(imgmat2).resize((100, 200))
imarr = np.array(imgrrr)
imarr = np.where(imarr == 0, 0, 1)

se_mat3 = np.array([
    [0,1,0],
    [1,1,1],
    [0,1,0]
])
se_mat31 = np.where(se_mat3 == 1, 0, 1)
```

The `imarr` is [image: the referenced image].

My implementation of erosion:

```py
%%cython -a
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp

cdef erosionC(cnp.ndarray[cnp.int_t, ndim=2] img, 
              cnp.ndarray[cnp.int_t, ndim=2] B, cnp.ndarray[cnp.int_t, ndim=2] X):
    """
    X: image coordinates
    struct_element_mat: black and white image, black region is considered as the shape 
                    of structuring element
                    
    This operation checks whether (B *includes* X) = $B \subset X$ 
    as per defined in
    Serra (Jean), « Introduction to mathematical morphology », 
    Computer Vision, Graphics, and Image Processing,
    vol. 35, nᵒ 3 (septembre 1986). 
    URL : https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/0734189X86900022.. 
    doi: 10.1016/0734-189X(86)90002-2
    Consulted le 6 août 2020, p. 283‑305.
    """
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.int_t, ndim=1] a, x, bx
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.int_t, ndim=2] Bx, B_frame, Xcp, b
    cdef bint check
    a = B[0] # get an anchor point from the structuring element coordinates
    B_frame = B - a # express the se element coordinates in with respect to anchor point
    Xcp = X.copy() 
    b = img.copy()
    for x in X: # X contains the foreground coordinates in the image
        Bx = B_frame + x # translate relative coordinates with respect to foreground coordinates considering it as the anchor point
        check = True # this is erosion so if any of the se coordinates is not in foreground coordinates we consider it a miss
        for bx in Bx: # Bx contains all the translated coordinates of se
            if bx not in Xcp:
                check = False
        if check:
            b[x[0], x[1]] = 1 # if there is a hit
        else:
            b[x[0], x[1]] = 0 # if there is no hit
    return b
        
def erosion(img: np.ndarray, struct_el_mat: np.ndarray, foregroundValue = 0):
    B = np.argwhere(struct_el_mat == 0)
    X = np.argwhere(img == foregroundValue)
    nimg = erosionC(img, B, X)
    return np.where(nimg == 1, 255, 0)
```

The calling code for both is:

```py
from scipy import ndimage as nd

err = nd.binary_erosion(imarr, se_mat3)

imerrCustom = erosion(imarr, se_mat31, foregroundValue=1)
```

`err` produces [image: this image]

`imerrCustom` produces [image: this image]

Comment: Allright I am deleting the other question

Comment: What is the output, and how does it differ from the expected one? I'm trying to read your code, but am having trouble understanding it. `if bx not in Xcp` I just can't make sense of the logic, it doesn't look like a dilation at all to me. I suggest that you use the image and the SE as matrices, rather than a list of coordinates. That will simplify your code significantly. At least in the sense that I'd be able to understand what is going on... Here is a similar question, with overly complicated code that I was able to simplify significantly: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63098284/7328782

Comment: Added the images as you said. The `bx not in Xcp` checks if the coordinates of the translated structuring element is included in the coordinates of the foreground of the image. I am adding comments to make it more easy to digest

Comment: So `imarr` is not a binary matrix, it has different levels. You should threshold it before applying the binary operator, so that you know what is considered foreground and background by each of the functions. ndimage probably considered any non-zero value to be foreground, but I'm not sure. Force it binary and you'll know for sure. Also, you seem to consider zero to be foreground? That is the opposite of what any other implementation does. Compare your erosion to the dilation of ndimage.

Comment: `imarr` is a binary matrix, it is just that the paper does not distinguish 0 or 1 as the foreground, so I thought I would let the user specify that, hence ` X = np.argwhere(img == foregroundValue)`, this is not the case for SE where I assume 0 as the indicator of the coordinates of SE

Comment: But now that you say it I should make sure that `imarr` is binary matrix, after resizing and transforming into numpy array.

Comment: The image you show for `imarr` is certainly not binary, there are intermediate gray values between black and white. Are you sure what happens to those in the binary erosion of ndimage?

Comment: Yes I just added the `np.where(imarr == 0, 0, 1)` to make sure everything is either 1 or 0

Comment: Also, as I said, ndimage's erosion (as any other implementation I know) will shrink the **white** part of the image (which it considers foreground. Yours will shrink the black part.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I am still not sure about it, but after having read several papers more, I assume that my interpretation of `X` as foreground coordinates was an error. It should have probably been the entire image that is being iterated.
As I have stated I am not sure if this interpretation is correct as well. But I made a new implementation which iterates over the image, and it gives a more plausible result. I am sharing it in here, hoping that it might help someone:

```py
%%cython -a
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp

cdef dilation_c(cnp.ndarray[cnp.uint8_t, ndim=2] X, 
                cnp.ndarray[cnp.uint8_t, ndim=2] SE):
    """
    X: boolean image
    SE: structuring element matrix
    origin: coordinate of the origin of the structuring element
                    
    This operation checks whether (B *hits* X) = $B \cap X \not = \emptyset$ 
    as per defined in
    Serra (Jean), « Introduction to mathematical morphology », 
    Computer Vision, Graphics, and Image Processing,
    vol. 35, nᵒ 3 (septembre 1986). 
    URL : https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/0734189X86900022.. 
    doi: 10.1016/0734-189X(86)90002-2
    Consulted le 6 août 2020, p. 283‑305.
    
    The algorithm adapts DILDIRECT of
    Najman (Laurent) et Talbot (Hugues), 
    Mathematical morphology: from theory to applications, 
    2013. ISBN : 9781118600788, p. 329
    to the formula given in 
    Jähne (Bernd), 
    Digital image processing, 
    6th rev. and ext. ed, Berlin ; New York, 
    2005. TA1637 .J34 2005. 
    ISBN : 978-3-540-24035-8.

    """
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.uint8_t, ndim=2] O
    cdef list elst
    cdef int r, c, X_rows, X_cols, SE_rows, SE_cols, se_r, se_c
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.int_t, ndim=1] bp
    cdef list conds
    cdef bint check, b, p, cond
    O = np.zeros_like(X)
    X_rows, X_cols = X.shape[:2]
    SE_rows, SE_cols = SE.shape[:2]
    # a boolean convolution
    for r in range(0, X_rows-SE_rows):
        for c in range(0, X_cols - SE_cols):
            conds = []
            for se_r in range(SE_rows):
                for se_c in range(SE_cols):
                    b = <bint>SE[se_r, se_c]
                    p = <bint>X[se_r+r, se_c+c]
                    conds.append(b and p)
            O[r,c] = <cnp.uint8_t>any(conds)
    return O
    
        
def dilation_erosion(
    img: np.ndarray, 
    struct_el_mat: np.ndarray, 
    foregroundValue: int = 1,
    isErosion: bool = False):
    """
    img: image matrix
    struct_el: NxN mesh grid of the structuring element whose center is SE's origin
              structuring element is encoded as 1 
    foregroundValue: value to be considered as foreground in the image
    """
    B = struct_el_mat.astype(np.uint8)
    if isErosion:
        X = np.where(img == foregroundValue, 0, 1).astype(np.uint8)
    else:
        X = np.where(img == foregroundValue, 1, 0).astype(np.uint8)

    nimg = dilation_c(X, B)
    foreground, background = (255, 0) if foregroundValue == 1 else (0, 1)
    if isErosion:
        return np.where(nimg == 1, background, foreground).astype(np.uint8)
    else:
        return np.where(nimg == 1, foreground, background).astype(np.uint8)
    # return nimg
```